# FF left table border disappears when wrapper's overflow-x is auto

Tags: css, html, firefox, html-table

When using a table with bordered cells, in FireFox the left table border disappears when the table is placed in wrapper with `overflow-x: auto`.

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: none;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

(also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zpwugncq/))

[A possible workaround I found:](https://jsfiddle.net/u4e9pz9o/)

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto; padding-left: 1px">
  <table style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: none;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This does happen on every FireFox version beginning from 4 (and possible earlier) up to 56. This behaviour seems totally specific to FF, as I wasn't able to reproduce it any version of IE, Opera, Safari, Android Browser or Chrome (even IE9 conforms here!). I couldn't find [any bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?component=Layout%3A%20Tables&product=Core&bug_status=__open__) directly mentioning this situation (only table rendering bug that is still open [albeit after 6 years *chuckles*] is [#688556](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556), but it concerns background painting, which is obviously not this case).

Is this a bug I should report, or am I missing some important piece of HTML5 spec here and it is an intended behaviour?

Comment: Report as a new bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I assume that this is not intended behaviour, I've submitted this as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1416504 . Again, the simplest workaround is to provide a left padding of width equal to `int( 0.5 * ( left_border_width + 1 ) )`.